# HTML&CSS: Оптимизационные аспекты разбиения стилевого файла на несколько

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивная-верстка, оптимизация-сайтов

Делая адаптивную вёрстку, добился того, чтобы в зависимости от ширины окна была разная вёрстка и разные стили. Теперь я задумался о том, чтобы для каждой фазы (диапазона ширин экрана, при котором вёрстка и стили не меняются) разбить слилевой файл на несколько. Что из нижеследующих альтернатив будет лучшим вариантом с точки зрения оптимизации? (Если у Вас есть ещё какие-либо соображения, пожалуйста, приведите их).

1. Поместить в head все стилевые файлы (применять одновременно будут стили только из 2 файлов, в остальных - медиазапросы для других фаз).

   ```
   <!--css-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style1.css" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style2.css" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style3.css" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style4.css" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style5.css" type="text/css">
   ```
2. Написать скрипт в JS, который при каждом изменеии фазы будет заменять в

   ```
   <!--css-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/styleN.css" type="text/css">
   ```

   N на номер фазы.

Если лучше второй способ, то как его лучше реализовать? По классу и идентификатору `<link>` не найти с помощью Jquery, получается остаётся только через `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: а почему _По классу и идентификатору <link> не найти с помощью Jquery_?

Comment: Если link можно присваивать классы и идентификаторы, то я не знал. До этого момента я и не мог подумать, что возникнет необходимость присваивать класс к тому, что не принимает участие в вёрстке и не отображается.

Comment: да можно присваивать и классы и id, и выбирать по имени тега

Comment: чтож, в таком случае как вариант можно и заменить соответствующий черз DOM стилевой файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте **Grunt**, куча модулей с удобными **LESS** или иными стилями. Но на продакшене все скомпилировано в одну ***min.css*** которая грузится быстрее и один раз. Также рекомендую при подключении css файла писать так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.min.css?date=<?=filemtime('path to file')?>" type="text/css">
```

Это поможет избежать кеширования css файла.
Тестируйте зесь https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/, гугл говорит чем меньше файлов и чем меньше их размер тем лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Существует общепринятая практика. Когда разработчик пишет код, располагаю модули (файлы css или js ...) как ему удобно. А потом система сборки собирает проект и упаковывает всё в один файл.

Пример, здесь я пишу css с помощью [процессора stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше моя система сборки, основанная на gulp собирает все css файлы в один и получается обычный css - понятный браузеру, но не такой удобный человеку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробности как сделать здесь: [в 4 серии описана сборка стилей](https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/gulp)